# Identify JavaScript function being called by text click

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing Google Translate with custom flag icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486833/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons)

I have the off-the-shelf google language translate widget on my webpage.  i'd like determine what javascript function is being called when i click the list of languages provided by the widget.

my goal is to have some flag icons (when clicked) call those same functions so they also trigger the language translation.

Comment: I forgot I asked this question already three months ago.  It was answered!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486833/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons

Comment: Maybe you could delete this question then.