# How we set Flags icon in google translator in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en', 
    includedLanguages: 'ar,de,en,nl,ru', 
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

I want to show flags in google translater with language text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Google Translate with custom flag icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486833/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons)

Comment: sir ,How we show flag with language text and how flag icon change ,when i change language?..         
Possible duplicate of Implementing Google Translate with custom flag icons give problems ..

Comment: The key is not to use the google widget but hide it and manage the functionality on your own widget. When user clicks on your widget you "click" on the hidden widget. Got it?