# Google Translate with custom option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to also be able to click on some option value in a html select I have and trigger the same javascript calls that the text-based links in the google translate widget.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9msobgh/)

```
 <html>

 <body>
  <select id="lang-drop">
            <option value="english">EN</option>
            <option value="spanish">SP</option>
    </select>
  translate -> text: open the door!
 </body>
 </html>
```

Anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this? I can't figure out how to make clicking on the option the same behavior as clicking on the google translate text links.

(i had see
 [Implementing Google Translate with custom flag icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486833/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons) but i work with jquery3.1 and this doesn't work...)

Comment: Show us what you have tried in js. That makes it eassier for us to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from [Implementing Google Translate with custom flag icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486833/implementing-google-translate-with-custom-flag-icons) works if you replace `!$frame.size()` with `!frame.length`.

For me the answer of *Boris Brdarić* works perfect.